# Put all the values user selects in a TimePicker in a list and read it

Tags: java, android, datetimepicker

The title may be a litle confusing. I have a TimePicker for the user to pick a duration of an event, I wan't to get every value the user puts in, save it, and then set the default value of the TimePicker to the time that the user selects the most times, so it may save him time.

For example, if the user constantly selects 1h and 45m, when he goes back to add another event it will be in 1h and 45m, so far I havn't tried anything because I don't know how, I only know how to define the starting value of the TimePicker.

```
timePickerDuration.setIs24HourView(true);    
timePickerDuration.setCurrentHour(1);
timePickerDuration.setCurrentMinute(30);
```

Comment: Pick the time save it as a string, Again pick another time save same as string and better adding those strings in an ArrayList, Then compare. Try once If you got any problem then you can freely ask.

Comment: Ok I tried this, but I'm missing the last step: http://imgur.com/Emj3Wo6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your try till here,
 If your `HoursList` ArrayList contains the proper value, then you can loop like this and find the mostly selected hour,

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (Integer i : HoursList) {
    Integer count = map.get(i);
    map.put(i, count != null ? count+1 : 0);
}

Integer mostlySelectedhr = Collections.max(map.entrySet(),
    new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<Integer, Integer> o1, Entry<Integer, Integer> o2) {
        return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
    }
}).getKey();
```

And finally `mostlySelectedhr` is the mostly selected hour.